# Async does wait for data to be returned in a redux-thunk function

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I've being trying populate my redux store with data that comes from my mongo-db realm database.
Whenever I run the function below it will execute fine but the problem is data will be delayed and ends up not reaching my redux store.

My thunk function:

```
export const addItemsTest = createAsyncThunk(
  "addItems",
  async (config: any) => {
    try {
      return await Realm.open(config).then(async (projectRealm) => {
        let syncItems = await projectRealm.objects("Item");
        await syncItems.addListener((x, changes) => {
          x.map(async (b) => {
            console.log(b);
            return b;
          });
        });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
);
```

and my redux reducer:

```
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
      builder.addCase(addItemsTest.fulfilled, (state, { payload }: any) => {
        try {
          console.log("from add Items");
          console.log(payload);
          state.push(payload);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
         }
      });
  }
```

**Expected Results:**
My redux store should have these data once `addItemsTest` return something:

```
[{
itemCode: 1,
itemDescription: 'Soccer Ball',
itemPrice: '35',
partition: 'partitionValue',
},
{
itemCode: 2,
itemDescription: 'Base Ball',
itemPrice: '60',
partition: 'partitionValue',
}
]
```

**Actual Results:**
[image: Console Results]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Mixed Syntaxes

You are combining `await`/`async` and `Promise.then()` syntax in a very confusing way.  It is not an error to mix the two syntaxes, but I do not recommend it.  Stick to just `await`/`async`

#### Void Return

Your action actually does not return any value right now because your inner `then` function doesn't return anything.  The only `return` is inside of the `then` is in the `x.map` callback.  `await syncItems` is the returned value *for the mapper*, not for your function.

Right now, here's what your thunk does:

- open a connection
- get items from realm
- add a listener to those items which logs the changes
- returns a `Promise` which resolves to `void`

#### Solution

I believe what you want is this:

```
export const addItemsTest = createAsyncThunk(
  "addItems",
  async (config: any) => {
    try {
      const projectRealm = await Realm.open(config);
      const syncItems = await projectRealm.objects("Item");
      console.log(syncItems);
      return syncItems;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
);
```

Without the logging, it can be simplified to:

```
export const addItemsTest = createAsyncThunk(
  "addItems",
  async (config: any) => {
    const projectRealm = await Realm.open(config);
    return await projectRealm.objects("Item");
  }
);
```

You don't need to `catch` errors because the `createAsyncThunk` will handle errors by dispatching an error action.

#### Edit: Listening To Changes

It seems that your intention is to  sync your redux store with changes in your Realm collection.  So you want to add a listener to the collection that calls `dispatch` with some action to process the changes.

Here I am assuming that this action takes an array with all of the items in your collection.  Something like this:

```
const processItems = createAction("processItems", (items: Item[]) => ({
  payload: items
}));
```

Replacing the entire array in your state is the easiest approach.  It will lead to some unnecessary re-renders when you replace item objects with identical versions, but that's not a big deal.

Alternatively, you could pass specific properties of the [changes](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-legacy/docs/javascript/latest/api/Realm.Collection.html#addListener) such as `insertions` and handle them in your reducer on a case-by-case basis.

In order to add a listener that dispatches `processItems`, we need access to two variables: the realm `config` and the redux `dispatch`.  You can do this in your component or by calling an "init" action.  I don't think there's really much difference.   You could do something in your reducer in response to the "init" action if you wanted.

Here's a function to add the listener.  The `Realm.Results` object is "array-like" but not exactly an array so we use `[...x]` to cast it to an array.

FYI this function may throw errors.  This is good if using in `createAsyncThunk`, but in a component we would want to `catch` those errors.

```
const loadCollection = async (config: Realm.Configuration, dispatch: Dispatch): Promise<void> => {
  const projectRealm = await Realm.open(config);
  const collection = await projectRealm.objects<Item>("Item");
  collection.addListener((x, changes) => {
    dispatch(processItems([...x]));
  });
}
```

Adding the listener through an intermediate `addListener` action creator:

```
export const addListener = createAsyncThunk(
  "init",
  async (config: Realm.Configuration, { dispatch }) => {
    return await loadCollection(config, dispatch);
  }
);

// is config a prop or an imported global variable?
const InitComponent = ({config}: {config: Realm.Configuration}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect( () => {
    dispatch(addListener(config));
  }, [config, dispatch]);

  /* ... */
}
```

Adding the listener directly:

```
const EffectComponent = ({config}: {config: Realm.Configuration}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect( () => {
    // async action in a useEffect need to be defined and then called
    const addListener = async () => {
      try {
        loadCollection(config, dispatch);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    }

    addListener();
    
  }, [config, dispatch]);

  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake on the code, could you please re-read it again, after the edit

Comment: Same issue.  You are still not returning anything.

Comment: Seems like he's trying to a listener which listen to changes on his database and then add whatever item if someone makes changes from a different device

Comment: I'm listening to changes on the database and actually need to run this function ```await syncItems.addListener```

Comment: @Fanyana that makes sense.  I was really not understanding the purpose of adding a listener in response to an action.  Seems like what's needed here is to add a listener that dispatches an action.  The adding of a listener could be totally separate from the action creator.

Comment: So you suggesting that I should execute such a function in component and the fire a dispatch?

Comment: Yeah you could definitely do it through a `useEffect` in your component.  I'm debating if that makes more sense then dispatching some sort of "init" action to do it.  You can access `dispatch` through the second argument in `createAsyncThunk`.  https://tsplay.dev/oN515N This "init" action itself has no payload, but the "processItems" action which is dispatched on change has a payload with the collection items. **edit:** should be `dispatch(processItems([...x]))` I think.

Comment: Could you show me how you would do interns of a function?

Comment: I'm editing my answer now.  Do you want to just add the change listener, or do you want to return the current items *and* add the listener?

Comment: I only want to add the listener only.

Comment: Still not working, when it reaches the reducer the return undefined and when new items are create it no longer reaches the reducer to add the item in the store

Comment: It doesn't matter anymore I've given up. I've being trying to use realm for months and still finding it hard to do simple things, I'm finally moving to firebase.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228703/discussion-between-tony-ngomana-and-linda-paiste).